# Permanently allow Google Cloud SDK access to your Google Account with Colaboratory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-workspace, google-cloud-sdk

When using Google Colaboratory with Google Cloud, one has to authenticate itself:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
print('Authenticated')
```

The result of running that cell is:

```
Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/......

Enter verification code:
```

Currently I have to grant it access and enter a new password every time I start a new notebook which makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Is there a way to permanently allow the Google Cloud SDK access to my Google Account?

Answer (score 3):

You can save credentials in the form of an API key that you write a file on disk. This still requires running a cell in each notebook to authenticate, but at least you don't have to click through the authentication flow each time.

See [Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) for creating an API key for a service account.

Then, in your notebook, write something like the following:

```
import os
storage_auth_info = r"""YOUR API KEY HERE"""
with open('/tmp/storage_auth_info.json', 'w') as f:
  f.write(storage_auth_info)
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '/tmp/storage_auth_info.json'
```

This will let anyone who has access to your notebook use the saved credentials, so use this with caution, e.g., consider only giving the service account read-only access to your data.